# Pinescript: How to put an Element in the Background?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v4

I am about to write my own indicator. I have a Line (a Moving Average) and a Plot (Money Flow). The Problem is, the Line is always behind the Plot (which is a bit transparent).

I have tried to plot the line after i plot the Plot in Pinescript but obviously this doesn't make a difference. So my question is, how can i set the Background Position of the Element to get sure, that the Plot is "behind" the Line

Answer (score 2):

You need to set the parameter `explicit_plot_zorder = true` inside your indicator/strategy() line. Once you set this parameter the z order of your plots will be according to the order they occur in your code.

https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v5/#fun_indicator

Comment: While explicit_plot_zorder = true works for a normal hline(), plot(), fill() it does not work for me when using line.new() or linefill.new() it always draws in the forground. If anyone knows a solution please share.